# Envio do token via header ou param

Tags: web-service, aplicação-web, api, jwt

Estou usando o `JWTAuth` para realizar a criação dos tokens para minha API.

Vi que no momento da requisição posso enviar o token no header ou via param.

Entendo que enviando via header o token acompanha a requisição de forma "transparente", resultando em uma aparência mais amigável.

Porém, fora a questão da aparência da requisição, existe algum outro motivo que me leve a escolher entre uma ou outra forma?

Alguma diferença de desempenho? Ou uma maior fragilidade na segurança? Por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na prática, nada te impede de passar o token através do header, request body ou query string.

De acordo com a [RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) o padrão de envio do token é através do Header **Authorization** ou de query string (ex: accessToken=meu-token).

Então:

> Porém, fora a questão da aparência da requisição, existe algum outro motivo que me leve a escolher entre uma ou outra forma?

Escolha o padrão já definido pra que outros desenvolvedores que forem dar manutenção no seu sistema ou fazer algum tipo de integração não precisem ficar adivinhando por onde é enviado o token.

> Alguma diferença de desempenho? Ou uma maior fragilidade na segurança?

Nenhuma diferença em desempenho. Em relação a segurança, garanta uma secret key forte para assinatura do token, não coloque dados sensíveis no payload e também utilize SSL na sua api.